# Azure Devops service connection to specific resource using serviceprincipal

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-devops-server-2019

Is it possible to create ADO service connection to a particular resource scope?

The requirement for the above question is that , we have our Loganalytic Workspace created in a separate subscription where the service principal doesn't have owner access. But if we get one of our service principal to create alert on Loganalytic workspace access alone, can we use the same service principal to create the service connection in ADO.

We have some pipeline task for the alert creation like "AzureCLI" and "AzureResourceGroupDeployment" where we need to use the ADO service connection to execute these tasks. But we are blocked with the service connection creation entirely to the subscription or resource group where the LAW is hosted. we are allowed only to get the access on LAW to execute the alert creation task.

In this scenario will the ADO service connection be possible?

If no, is there any way to pass service principal credential directly in above ADO tasks (where we are using azurecli and group deployment tasks)?

Example, We have subscription `Sub-A` and a serviceprincipal `SP-A` within that subscription. By using ADO service connection with service principal `SP-A` within the Subscription `Sub-A` , we can run `ADO` tasks like `azureCli` and `resourcegroup deployment` etc in `Sub-A` and able to create Loganalytic alert rules in `LAW` in that Subscription `Sub-A`, as the serviceprincipal `SP-A` has owner access to that Subscription `Sub-A`.

But we have to use same pipelines to create alerts in another Loganalytic workspace in subscription `Sub-B`, with the same kind of approach we used in the pipeline (using serviceconnection cli and rgdeployment tasks), where in Subscription B, the serviceprincipal doesnt have owner access. We are restricted to get alert creation access alone in that LAW in Subscription B. So here inorder to automate the alert cration, In ADO can we create serviceconnection without having owner access to subs B for SP-A. or can we specify the AZ group deploy and azurecli tasks in ADO by specifying the serviceprincipal credential to achive our requirement

Comment: Can you clarify the explanation by naming things "subscription A, subscription B, service principal X, service principal Y". A service connection just uses a service principal. A service principal is defined at tenant / AD level, and this crosses subscriptions. So if your service principal has adequate access it can do anything in your tenant / AD

Comment: example session added to the question

Comment: Do you have a service principal with required access in Sub B? If you don’t, and you can’t get one created, that’s the end of the story.

Comment: Can you explain the what is this required accessyou mentioned  for the service principal on Subscription B? There are situations like we cant grant the full access for serviceprincipal across all subscriptions. and here in our scenario, we will get only specific access to create alert rule in Loganalytic workspace for the serviceprincipal and not subscription wide. In that case I guess  ADO service connection is not possible

Comment: _Can you explain the what is this required accessyou mention_ ... is what access _you_ require to do whatever you want to do. I have no idea what that is.

Comment: i am looking for creating alert rule creation in Loganalytic workspace in different subscriotion, and i have a service principal without having any access on that subscription. So requirement here is that i will be allowed to get the least privilege to accomplish this requirement. So what will be the minimum level of access required for this to create the alert rule using arm template methood in Azuredevops ? with this minimal access of Serviceprincipal, can we create a service conenction in ADO to that subscription ?

Comment: I googled (like I do for 95% of questions on here) and found this, explaining what roles your service principal will require: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/392288/create-alert-rule.html

Comment: You need to grant your service connection "monitoring contributor or monitoring reader RBAC role at the subscription level". If this can't / won't be done, then you can't do the required action. end of story. There's no way to raise your access with your own bootstraps.

Comment: "with this minimal access of Serviceprincipal, can we create a service conenction in ADO to that subscription". I think you're asking: can I grant myself required access via DevOps? Unless there is some kind of security hole, you can rarely raise your access level via another security principal.